# how can i get an attacment to attach to an email in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

Im trying to create a script that at the push of a button will send an email with an attachment to a given email address. So far, it has the following problem on line 28

4:55:13 PM  Error
Exception: Invalid argument: attachments
mtnPdfExport    @ mtn email.gs:28

I cant figure out how to get the attachment to actually attach to the email so it can send.

Here is my script:

```
function mtnPdfExport() {
 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MTN")
  var exportNameMtn = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("X").getRange("BH11").getValue();

 for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== "MTN") {
  sheets[i].hideSheet()
    }
  }
  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(ss.getBlob());
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== "MTN" && sheets[i].getSheetName() !== "CB2" && sheets[i].getSheetName() !== "X") 
sheets[i].showSheet()
  }

  newFile.setName(nameMtnSheet());
  newFile.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById("1JBOod0Su8GwGH49ntejRWpjCSwoHVWhy")); 

 let attachPdf = DriveApp.getFolderById("1JBOod0Su8GwGH49ntejRWpjCSwoHVWhy").getFilesByName(nameMtnSheet);

 var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DASH");

 activeSheet.activate();

 GmailApp.sendEmail("testemailme@gmail.com","Mtnland customer job sheet","Hi guys attached is a new customer account, thanks!", {attachments:attachPdf});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- If your error of `4:55:13 PM Error Exception: Invalid argument: attachments mtnPdfExport @ mtn email.gs:28` is from `GmailApp.sendEmail("testemailme@gmail.com","Mtnland customer job sheet","Hi guys attached is a new customer account, thanks!", {attachments:attachPdf});`, in your script, `nameMtnSheet()` and `nameMtnSheet` are not declared. So, an error occurs before the line. So, I guessed that in your actual script, it supposes that those have already been declared elsewhere. Please be careful about this.
- When it supposes that all scripts except for `GmailApp.sendEmail("testemailme@gmail.com","Mtnland customer job sheet","Hi guys attached is a new customer account, thanks!", {attachments:attachPdf});` works fine, `attachPdf` of `let attachPdf = DriveApp.getFolderById("1JBOod0Su8GwGH49ntejRWpjCSwoHVWhy").getFilesByName(nameMtnSheet);` is `DriveApp.FileIterator`. In the current stage, this cannot be directly used as the attachment file. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.
- In your script, I think that `newFile` can be used.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function mtnPdfExport() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MTN")
  var exportNameMtn = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("X").getRange("BH11").getValue(); // It seems that this variable is not used.
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== "MTN") {
      sheets[i].hideSheet();
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // This line might not be required to be used.
  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(ss.getBlob());
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== "MTN" && sheets[i].getSheetName() !== "CB2" && sheets[i].getSheetName() !== "X") {
      sheets[i].showSheet();
    }
  }
  newFile.setName(nameMtnSheet());
  newFile.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById("1JBOod0Su8GwGH49ntejRWpjCSwoHVWhy"));
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DASH");
  activeSheet.activate();
  GmailApp.sendEmail("testemailme@gmail.com", "Mtnland customer job sheet", "Hi guys attached is a new customer account, thanks!", { attachments: [newFile] });
}
```

- In this modification, it supposes that `nameMtnSheet()` has already been declared elsewhere. Please be careful about this.